# Прямая и обратная сортировка в сервлете

Tags: java, сортировка

Подскажите как реализовать сортировку данных в таблице чтобы при нажатии одной и той же кнопки алгоритм сортировал данные на сервлете сначала в прямом, а потом в обратном порядке. Буду рад примерам кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните себе какой-то флаг. Вроде `isReverseOrder = false`. Собственно когда обрабатываете клик то смотрите на флаг и в зависимости от флага сортируете как вам надо. Что-то вроде такого:

```
view.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (isReverseOrder) {
                    Collections.sort(collection, Collections.reverseOrder());
                    isReverseOrder = false;
                } else {
                    Collections.sort(collection);
                    isReverseOrder = true;
                }
            });
```